# Django, move variables

Tags: python, django, middleware

I have a standard django application. In a view (let's name it First) I call an HttpResponseRedirect (to the view called Second) however there is some data I'd like to transfer to the Second view. What options do I have to achieve this?

One would be to set a GET parameter, however this is not a nice solution.

I also could set a session variable, but this is also not the best solution.

Do I have any other possibility? For example could I use some context processor or something similar?

My question might contain not all the information, but I hope someone can give me a good tip.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited your English a bit: we wouldn't use contractions in phrases like "what options do I have".

Comment: Hi, nope, thanks, i read the corrections. My mother tongue is not english, so at least i learned from it :- ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say that session variables are not the best solution. On the contrary, they are absolutely the right solution for doing this.

In the first view, you can simply do `request.session['first_data'] = my_data`, and in the second, `my_data = request.session.pop('first_data')`.

Comment: Yes, this solution works. That' s a fact, but i' d like to know is there any other possibilities i could use? Of course it happens plenty of times, so at the end i' d use a context processor to process the session variable, but still, i' m just curious. I didn' t find any other possibility.

Comment: Second of all i' m not that very satisfied with sessions if You' ve more instances open from the same page.

Comment: Obviously the second function knows what data it needs. Therefore, it should take this information as arguments, therefore you should do this via a `reverse` -  sessions are useful for longer-term caching of information, but for an immediate function call, there's no need to make a db hit.

Comment: No, the second doesn' t know it. It' s beyond it. There are many Second type views, so the logic should be beyond this. If i use a session, i can use context processor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the Second view takes some arguments, and these are what you want to pass. You should use the reverse() function to pass them - it will create a url and the arguments will go where they're needed. For example, if `second` is a function taking two arguments, you might do something like this:

```
HttpResponseRedirect( reverse (second, urlconf = "myapp.urls", args = ['foo arg', 2]))
```

If the data you want to pass does not correspond to the `second` function's arguments, then sessions might be a reasonable fallback - but then you have to ask yourself, why not?